# C# Unflatten JSON object having Space Separated Keys

Tags: c#, json

Requirement: My json file can have nested fields. I need to remove certain fields and reconstruct the json.
To remove nested fields I thought of flattening the JSON to iDictionary<string, Object>, remove the appropriate fields and Unflatten it. Unfortunately the reconstructed JSON doesn't seem to be in expected format. Refer the below Input and Output json.

InputFile.json:

```
{
    "First Name" : "Steve",
    "Last Name" : "Williams",
    "Age" : 20,
    "Employement Details" : {
        "Organization" : "Google",
        "SalaryReceived" : 25000,
        "Designation" : "Senior Engineer"
    }
}
```

After flattening and unflattening, the output json file is: OutputFile.json

```
{
  "'First": {
    "Name'": "Steve"
  },
  "'Last": {
    "Name'": "Williams"
  },
  "Age": 20,
  "'Employement": {
    "Details'": {
      "Organization": "Google",
      "SalaryReceived": 25000,
      "Designation": "Senior Engineer"
    }
  }
}
```

I am using a library 'JsonFlatten' from Nuget Package. It is adding Flatten and UnFlatten extension methods to JObject.

How to bring back original JSON file structure after unflattening it. Please note that I have *NO* issues with flatten/unflatten when the field names doesn't contain whitespaces.

```
string InputJson = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Learnings\InputFile.json");
JObject jsonObject = JObject.Parse(InputJson);
var flattenedObj = jsonObject.Flatten();
var unFlattenObj = flattenedObj.Unflatten();

var JsonOutput = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(unFlattenObj);
Console.WriteLine(JsonOutput);
File.WriteAllText(@"C:\Learnings\OutputFile.json", JsonOutput);
```

Comment: what is your expected json?

Comment: I am just flattening and unflattening it. I am expecting output json to be similar to input json.

Answer (score 0):

You can add more properties to the list `itemsToRemove` as you wish.

```
        string InputJson = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Learnings\InputFile.json");
        var itemsToRemove = new List<string>() { "Organization" };
        var jObj = JObject.Parse(InputJson);

        jObj.Descendants().OfType<JProperty>()
            .Where(p => itemsToRemove.Contains(p.Name))
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(p => p.Remove());

        var newjson = jObj.ToString();
        Console.WriteLine(newjson);
```